# Concatenating columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
index  country   value1   value2   value3
  0      USA      6         5        4
  1      USA      4         7        3
  2      USA      3         2        1
  3      CAN      4         5        7
  4      CAN      10        8        6
```

I want to convert this to a column-oriented dataframe like below for each value (i.e. value1, value2 or value3)

The first dataframe for value1 should look like this:

```
index   USA     CAN
  0      6       4 
  1      4       10
  2      3       NaN
```

I have tried this code

```
column = ['USA', 'CAN']
df_value1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=column)
temp = df['value1'].where(df['country']=='USA').dropna()
df_value1['USA'] = temp
temp = df['value1'].where(df['country']=='CAN').dropna()
pd.concat([df_value1, temp], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

When I concatenate along the column (axis=1) since CAN values start from row 3 I get the resulting df_vaue1 dataframe like this:

```
index   USA     CAN
  0      6       NaN
  1      4       NaN
  2      3       NaN
  3     NaN       4
  4     NaN       10
```

But I want the df_value1 dataframe like this:

```
index   USA     CAN
  0      6       4 
  1      4       10
  2      3       NaN
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume `index` is the index of your `df`. You need to `set_index` on `country` and `cumcount`, and `unstack`

```
df1 = df.set_index([df.groupby('country').cumcount(), 'country']).unstack()
```

if `index` is a column of your `df`, you need additional `drop` as follows

```
df1 = df.drop('index',1).set_index([df.groupby('country').cumcount(), 'country']).unstack()


Out[1959]:
        value1      value2      value3
country    CAN  USA    CAN  USA    CAN  USA
0          4.0  6.0    5.0  5.0    7.0  4.0
1         10.0  4.0    8.0  7.0    6.0  3.0
2          NaN  3.0    NaN  2.0    NaN  1.0
```

From `df1` above, if you need `value1`, just do slicing as follows:

```
df1['value1']

Out[1960]:
country   CAN  USA
0         4.0  6.0
1        10.0  4.0
2         NaN  3.0
```

Comment: Thank you Andy L. The index I mentioned is the index of my df.

Comment: This code worked wonders. Thank you. df1 = df.set_index([df.groupby('country').cumcount(), 'country']).unstack()

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
import itertools
dataframes = {}
for v in df.filter(like='value').columns:
    nest = [df[v].loc[col] for col in cols]
    dataframes[v] = pd.DataFrame((y for y in itertools.zip_longest(*nest)), columns=cols)
```

So that, `dataframes['value1']` gives:

```
  USA   CAN
0   6   4.0
1   4   10.0
2   3   NaN
```